# Not a class, namespace or enumeration with templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to run this code and it throws error. I couldn't figure out why this is the case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename... Args>
struct type_list
{
    template <std::size_t N>
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
};

template<typename... Ts>
bool foo(unsigned int position)
{
    type_list<Ts...> x;
    return typeid(x::type<0>) == typeid(true);
}

int main()
{
    bool r = foo<int, int>(0);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << r;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
  main.cpp: In function 'bool foo(unsigned int)':
  main.cpp:16:19: error: 'x' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
   return typeid(x::type<0>) == typeid(true);
               ^

  main.cpp:16:29: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

   return typeid(x::type<0>) == typeid(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message said, `x` is an object, not a class, namespace, or enumeration.

I suppose you want

```
return typeid(typename type_list<Ts...>::template type<0>) == typeid(true);
```

or you can use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) (since C++11) with `x`

```
return typeid(typename decltype(x)::template type<0>) == typeid(true);
```

Comment: Awesome! that works. My template experience is very basic. Sorry if I posted something silly but I really needed to save my time.

Comment: @replimisg Yes templates might make it complex but the real problem it that you need to differentiate names between objects and types (or namespaces).